# Dirichlet Problem for Quasi-linear Parabolic Equation that Degenerates at Endpoints

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, mean-curvature-flows

**The equation:**

Let $\Omega = (0,1) \times (0, T) \subset \mathbb R \times \mathbb R.\\$

I would like to find a solution $u(t,x)$ to the following Dirichlet problem:

$$
u_t = h(x, u) \frac{u_{xx}}{1+(u_x)^2} \hspace{5mm}\textrm{ on } \Omega,
$$
and 
$$
u(0,x) =u_0(x); \quad u(t,0)  = u(t,1)= 0.
$$

This equation is of the form:
$$
u_t = a(t,x,u,u_x) u_{xx},
$$
where
$$
a(t,x,u,u_x) =  \frac{h(x,u)}{1+(u_x)^2}.
$$
So it is quasi-linear. It is also (non-uniformly) parabolic, since $h>0$ on $\Omega$ (but goes to $0$ at $x= 0,1$).

**Info about $h$:**
$$0 < h(t,x,u) \leq 1 \quad \textrm{for }\quad x\in (0,1). $$
and 
$$
h(0,u) = h(1,u) = 0 \quad \textrm{for} \quad t\in [0,T).
$$

**Observations:** I have come across this equation in my work, but I don't have much experience with parabolic PDE. So far, looking at the literature on quasi-linear parabolic pde, I am unable to find much theory that I can apply. The main issue seems to be that the equation is not uniformly parabolic, as $a(t,x,u,u_x)$ goes to $0$ at the endpoints, and so I am unable to use any of the results in [[LSU]](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-23).

It may be relevant that $u_t = \frac{u_{xx}}{1+(u_x)^2}$ is the equation for graphical mean curvature flow (MCF), so this equation could be considered a modified curvature flow. Since the MCF can be solved for all time, my hope was that because $h$ is fairly well behaved (bounded, smooth, non-negative, etc), this equation might be too.

**My question:**

Does any existing theory cover this type of problem, or are there standard ways to get around this degeneracy at the endpoints?

Comment: This is an interesting question. It may be useful to consider some very special linear versions first. The linear equation $u_t = \left(x(1-x)u_x\right)_x = x(1-x)u_{xx} + (1-2x)u_x$ may be solved by separation of variables in terms of Legendre polynomials. And the equation $u_t = x(1-x)u_{xx}$ may be studied in terms of Gegenbauer polynomials (I think). Due to the linear degeneracy of the weight function $h$ at $x = 0,1$, no boundary condition is required.

Comment: @HansEngler   Thanks, I'll check those out! Assuming this goes well, do you have any suggestions on where to go from there to address the original problem?